# Helper that swaps out some text for certain icons

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails helper that swaps out some text for certain icons.

Example:

**Helper Sample**

```
...
            '+1' => '<i class="ms ms-loyalty-up ms-loyalty-1"></i>',
            '+2' => '<i class="ms ms-loyalty-up ms-loyalty-2"></i>',
            '−1' => '<i class="ms ms-loyalty-down ms-loyalty-1"></i>',
            '−2' => '<i class="ms ms-loyalty-down ms-loyalty-2"></i>',
            '−10' => '<i class="ms ms-loyalty-down ms-loyalty-10"></i>',
            '{T}' => '<i class="ms ms-tap"></i>',
            '{P}' => '<i class="ms ms-tap"></i>',
            '{C}' => '<i class="ms ms-c"></i>'
            }
card.gsub(/\{.+?\}|\+\d+|\−\d+|\{[T]}|X/){|k| hash[k] || k }.html_safe
```

There is about 30 lines above that, but I'm about to have to duplicate this +1, +2, -1, -2 one etc to include every number between 1 and 20. This seems -extremely- poor practice and I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it? Below is my entire helper, and I might be able to cross apply it to text too, but it seems very silly to me to have to do it for all numbers, both positive and negative.

(As you can tell `ms-loyalty-down` is for negative numbers and `ms-loyalty-up` is for positive.) I was thinking about a 'case' and 'when case +' loyalty-up, but I wasn't getting the number appended to the end, nor was it continuing through the cycle.

**Entire Helper**

```
module CardsHelper
    def card_text_swap card
        if card.nil ?
            return
        else
            hash = {
                '{hw}' => '<span class="ms-half"> <i class = "ms ms-w ms-cost"> </i> </span>', 
                '{W}' => '<i class="ms ms-w ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{R}' => '<i class="ms ms-r ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{U}' => '<i class="ms ms-u ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{G}' => '<i class="ms ms-g ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{B}' => '<i class="ms ms-b ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{S}' => '<i class="ms ms-s ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{X}' => '<i class="ms ms-x ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                'X' => '<i class="ms ms-x ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{W/U}' => '<i class="ms ms-wu ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{W/B}' => '<i class="ms ms-wb ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{W/P}' => '<i class="ms ms-wp ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{2/W}' => '<i class="ms ms-2w ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{U/B}' => '<i class="ms ms-ub ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{U/R}' => '<i class="ms ms-ur ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{U/P}' => '<i class="ms ms-up ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{2/U}' => '<i class="ms ms-2u ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{B/R}' => '<i class="ms ms-br ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{B/G}' => '<i class="ms ms-bg ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{B/P}' => '<i class="ms ms-bp ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{2/B}' => '<i class="ms ms-2b ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{R/G}' => '<i class="ms ms-rg ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{R/P}' => '<i class="ms ms-rp ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{R/W}' => '<i class="ms ms-rw ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{2/R}' => '<i class="ms ms-2r ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{G/W}' => '<i class="ms ms-gw ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{G/B}' => '<i class="ms ms-gb ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{G/P}' => '<i class="ms ms-gp ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{2/G}' => '<i class="ms ms-2g ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{0}' => '<i class="ms ms-0 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{1}' => '<i class="ms ms-1 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{2}' => '<i class="ms ms-2 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{3}' => '<i class="ms ms-3 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{4}' => '<i class="ms ms-4 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{5}' => '<i class="ms ms-5 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{6}' => '<i class="ms ms-6 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{7}' => '<i class="ms ms-7 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{8}' => '<i class="ms ms-8 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{9}' => '<i class="ms ms-9 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{10}' => '<i class="ms ms-10 ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '+1' => '<i class="ms ms-loyalty-up ms-loyalty-1"></i>',
                '+2' => '<i class="ms ms-loyalty-up ms-loyalty-2"></i>',
                '−1' => '<i class="ms ms-loyalty-down ms-loyalty-1"></i>',
                '−2' => '<i class="ms ms-loyalty-down ms-loyalty-2"></i>',
                '−10' => '<i class="ms ms-loyalty-down ms-loyalty-10"></i>',
                '{T}' => '<i class="ms ms-tap"></i>',
                '{P}' => '<i class="ms ms-tap"></i>',
                '{C}' => '<i class="ms ms-c"></i>'
            }
            card.gsub(/\{.+?\}|\+\d+|\−\d+|\{[T]}|X/) { | k | hash[k] || k
            }.html_safe
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: In the refactored version, you need `hash = hash.merge(repetitive_cost_entries)` or use the mutating version (i don't recommend this) `hash.merge!(repetitive_cost_entries)`.  also, use a guard clause at the top instead of a big `if... else`:  `return if card.nil?`.  finally, just a naming nitpick, i'd remove the `repetitive_` prefix from the vars at the top.  in my example i'd only included it so that, conceptually, it would be clear what i was suggesting.

Comment: @Jonah You're right. I forget about that, such a simple fix. I appreciate the nit-picking! Naming conventions is a failure of mine.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the entries programmatically:

```
repetitive_entries = (1..10).map do |i|
  ["+#{i}", "<i class=\"ms ms-loyalty-up ms-loyalty-#{i}\"></i>"]
end.to_h
```

So then your overall strategy would be:

1. Create the one-off entries in `card` as you have now
2. Create the repetitive entries that differ only by a number
3. Repeat step 2 as many times as needed, eg, for the "up" and "down" versions.
4. Use array `merge` to combine the hashes from the previous steps into one large hash.

This allows you to keep your current approach, which I like for its simplicity, and avoid repeating yourself.

Comment: I actually like this. Still seems a bit repetitive, but isn't -nearly- as bad as my current usage. I'll try it out.

Comment: you could certainly go one level of abstraction higher and avoid all the repetition.  my approach would be to start with the rewrite above, then re-evaluate after seeing the new code, and decide if the gain in compactness would be worth the cognitive overhead of the new abstraction.  it's a good general principle when refactoring

Comment: Do you see anything wrong with my refactored version? I actually checked in console and it's giving me the results I would expect, but with the gsub I'm no longer getting proper expectations (AKA The number is still being output, not the <I>)